# Getting error for initializing a structure in C

Tags: c

I am getting an error when trying to compile a C source file that uses a structure.
I'm using gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here is the code:

```
/* struct.c: Illustrates structures */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Hitter {
    char last[16];
    char first[11];
    int home_runs;
};

int main() {
    struct Hitter h1 = {"McGwire", "Mark", 70};
    struct Hitter h2;
    strcpy(h2.last, "Sosa");
    strcpy(h2.first, "Sammy");
    h2.home_runs = h1.home_runs - 4;
    printf("#1 == {%s, %s, %d}\n",
           h1.last, h1.first, h1.home_runs);
    printf("#2 == {%s, %s, %d}\n",
           h2.last, h2.first, h2.home_runs);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the error:

```
$ gcc -o struct struct.c
struct.c: In function `main':
struct.c:12:9: error: parameter `h1' is initialized
struct.c:14:2: error: expected declaration specifiers before `strcpy'
struct.c:15:2: error: expected declaration specifiers before `strcpy'
struct.c:16:2: error: expected declaration specifiers before `h2'
struct.c:18:2: error: expected declaration specifiers before `printf'
struct.c:21:2: error: expected declaration specifiers before `printf'
struct.c:23:2: error: expected declaration specifiers before `return'
struct.c:24:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before `}' token
struct.c:13:16: error: declaration for parameter `h2' but no such parameter
struct.c:12:16: error: declaration for parameter `h1' but no such parameter
struct.c:24:1: error: expected `{' at end of input
```

The above code is from the CD training course "Thinking in C" by Chuck Allison. I know that is a very old CD and I am sure the syntax of the structure must have changed, but I have no idea what it may be now. Your help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: At first glance this code seems OK to me.

Comment: @Mat seems that the version number of GCC is negative...

Comment: Strange, I'm using gcc 4.5.2 and it compiles fine.

Comment: Can you upload the output of `gcc -E struct.c` to a site like gist.github.com?

Comment: gcc 4.0.01 and 4.2.1 both accept this code without comment on my mac. Even with `-Wall -strict`.

Comment: Looks like the code you've posted isn't what you have in your file, or you have funky chars in your file. The error message states `h1` is a parameter, which it isn't. And the `{}` are perfectly balanced. Either that or one of the standard headers got screwed up, but that's unlikely.

Comment: running the same version of ubuntu here. i have copy pasted your code and it's working. try updating you compiler.

Comment: hmm. What happens if you remove the 2 #include?

Comment: At the command line where you're typing the `gcc` command, do `cat struct.c`. Make sure it looks like what you've got open in your editor. (I've gotten confused before when I've got a file in my editor that's open to a different directory -- usually after I move/rename the file and forget to close/reopen the file in my editor.)

Comment: Compiles just fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Once I've had a similar case and it turned out the file I was trying to compile had incorrect line endings. For example, your file taken from disk might have CR + LF as end of line, while only LF is expected. This can be discovered by turning an option to show invisible characters in most of text editors.

Comment: This helped me change my editor settings when working in Windows and compiling in Linux.  Thanks.